# Specific sequence of phrases in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1muWO.png)

Using Matcher or PhraseMatcher, how can I create patterns that get sequences of phrases in a Doc, so that those phrases are found in a specific order. For example, as shown in the image, the pattern should catch the sequence of phrases: "OLE DB", "Client unable", "remote host" in that same order but in different locations within the Doc.

A list of phrases that is read from a json file. Each phrase is a Doc that is passed to the PhraseMatcher.

```
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
ERRORS = {}

with open("./errors.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    ERRORS = json.loads(f.read())

for key, value in ERRORS.items():
    patterns = list(nlp.pipe(value))
    matcher.add(key, patterns)
```